# One column for compact and two columns for regular size classes

Tags: ios, swift

I need to create responsive template.

If device has Regular width, I need to display two columns in UITableView.

If device has Compact width, I need to display one column in UITableView.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView only supports a single column. To use UITableView, you'd have to try and line up columns within each cell and probably not wind up with an optimal experience (also after much more work than needed).  You should look at [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) instead for something like this.